# Two values in one input type=text

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am currently working on a "garage" function in php where I have a `$car_id`, and a `$city_id`. I want to have the ability to sell x amount of cars in the chosen city.

Since I have the same `$car_id` on a multiple cars, ex. `$car_id[0] = "Chevy"` there is a problem when I try to sell the chevy in city 0 and not city 1, because it only takes the amount of chevy's and not splitting them by city.

I am wondering if it is any possible way to get 2 values from an input field. ex. `['city']['car_id']`

`<input type="text" name="['city']['car_id']" placeholder="0">`

I want to have the ability to write in this input "10", and it will sell 10 of the cars in the given city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is working with the concept of fieldsets. Think about the three different values of the car, the city and the amount of cars are stored in a container.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="values[0][car_id]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="values[0][city_id]" value="1">
        <input type="number" name="values[0][amount]" value="0" min="0" max="10">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="values[1][car_id]" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="values[1][city_id]" value="1">
        <input type="number" name="values[1][amount]" value="0" min="0" max="10">
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see the name attributes of the input elements is stated with `values[n][name]`. `n` is the count of the iterator. `name` is the specific name of the property. This results in a multidimensional array, which holds the input data. This ensures the assignment of the various attributes to each other. The amount of a specific car in a specific city.

This structure assumes that you iterate over the different cities. Each city can contain several vehicles for which you can specify a certain amount.

If you fill out and submit the above given form it results in the following `$_POST` data structure.

```
array(2) {
    ["values"] => array(2) {
        [0] => array(3) {
            ["car_id"] => string(1) "1"
            ["city_id"] => string(1) "1"
            ["amount"] => string(1) "1"
        }
        [1] => array(3) {
            ["car_id"] => string(1) "2"
            ["city_id"] => string(1) "1"
            ["amount"] => string(1) "2"
        }
    }
    ["submit"] => string(9) "Save"
}
```

This structure is easy to iterate.

```
foreach ($_POST['values'] as $data) {
    echo "City ID: " . $data['city_id'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Car ID: " . $data['car_id'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Amount: " . $data['amount'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This solution represents exactly what you want to have. A set of a specific car for a specific city.

Comment: Thanks alot! Saved me from paracetamol today